# Google Maps Functionality

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to create an embedded Google Maps on my non profit website.  I've asked around to a few "professional" developers, and they all want thousands of dollars... in case you missed it, this is a non profit.

What I want to do is embed a Google Map on my website that will:

Allow anonymous users to type in an intersection, (ie: Woodward and Fort), grab the map, pan and zoom.

Allow users to anonymously add markers to the map.  These markers will be pre-set, one for "suspected drug activity," another for "illegal dumping," "dangerous structure," etc...

Allow users to anonymously comment on those markers and have that activity take place in an "Info Box" on that marker.  The comments should be saved in the info box for other anonymous users to see.  It'd be nice if there were some way I, as an admin, could have those comments appear in a custom admin window so they can be easily printed out and taken to the police.

Allow only the site administrator to delete markers.

The anonymous users should not be able to move or delete a marker once its placed.  Whatever happens on the map should pretty much stay there for anyone to see until it gets deleted by an admin.

Long story short, I live in Detroit, MI and have my entire life.  I've traveled the world, but home is home and I love it.  I see young people like myself being passionate about the city but most of us don't know how to engage and even though we're outraged by whats going on in our neighborhoods, we're complicitly silent on the problems.  I want to create this site so people can keep a public record of the problems in the neighborhoods so the police can do something about it.  A second map would share positive news on the city to show that its not all doom and gloom and there are things that are beautiful, fun, safe, and worth-while here.

If you don't mind pitching in some time to help, I'd appreciate it very much.  But if you've got an idea on how to code it, I can try to do it myself.

Thanks for reading, and thanks for your input.

---

Thanks everyone for your support. In response to Duncan here is my specific question:

How can I embed a map on my site but still have a place for visitors to type in an intersection and be taken there while still on my site?

Thanks!

Comment: Kind of a big project for free, but I love the idea! Best of luck.

Comment: I can just agree with the previous comment. Good luck with it.

Comment: This question is likely to get closed, unless you can narrow it down to a specific programming problem you're stuck with.  Take a look at sites like http://www.fixmystreet.com/ and http://www.mysociety.org/projects/diy-mysociety/

Answer (score 0):

Google provides a pretty basic tutorial for implementing google maps here:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial